# Relative URL to a sub-directory in HTML

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, anchor, relative-url

Can we create a relative link in HTML? For example, how can I write a relative URL on this page

> http://www.example.com/dir/sub-dir

to this sub page

> http://www.example.com/dir/sub-dir/sub-sub-dir

Is this even possible in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.... just write it relative:

```
<a href="sub-sub-dir">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
<a href="./sub-sub-dir">LINK1</a>
```

or just

```
<a href="sub-sub-dir">LINK2</a>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html